# InMemoryBackendService error collection.reduce is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am trying to mock a login component that does an http post with credentials to an auth endpoint that returns a json object containing a token and some other info.

Getting a "500 Internal server error" response, upon further inspection I see more information in the body of the response...

```
error:"collection.reduce is not a function"
```

here is my seed data file

```
export class AppData {
  createDb() {
    let auth = {
      access_token: '2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA',
      token_type: 'bearer',
      expires_in: 3500
    };
    return {auth};
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
public authenticateUser(user:string, pass:string):Promise<AuthResponseModel> {


    // TODO: Hit auth endpoint
    let authUrl = 'app/auth';
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username: user, password: pass});

    return this.http.post(authUrl, body, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((res: Response) => {
            let body = res.json();
            return body.data || { };
        },(reason:any) => {
            console.log('authenticateUser() error %o ', reason);
            return Promise.reject(reason);

        })
        .catch(this.handleError);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

InMemoryBackendService only works with collections. So it's fairly useless for mocking services other than simple CRUD endpoints.